# Bootstrap thumbnail min width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please see the images below
[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: image 3]

I am using bootstrap thumbnails. When i reduce my screen size using chrome's inpscet element, i get thumbnails as in image1, on further reducing i see the "Go to Page" and "View Details" buttons disorient. When i further reduce the screen size, number of images in a row reduces and again the buttons are aligned properly as in image3. 
Please help me to **increase the minimum width for my thumbnails which will lead me from image1 to image3**... that is **prevent dis-orienting the button positions.**

here is the code for page content

```
 <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1 class="page-header">Home</h1>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
                </div>
                <style>
                    .thumbnail{
                       // min-width: 240px;
                    }
                </style>
                <!-- /.row -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            Recently added
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class=" col-md-4">
                                  <div class="thumbnail">
                                      <img src="<?php echo base_url()."assets/images/placeholder.jpg" ?>" alt="...">
                                    <div class="caption">
                                      <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                                      <p>...</p>
                                      <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Go to page</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default pull-right" role="button">View Details</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class=" col-md-4">
                                  <div class="thumbnail">
                                      <img src="<?php echo base_url()."assets/images/placeholder.jpg" ?>" alt="...">
                                    <div class="caption">
                                      <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                                      <p>...</p>
                                      <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Go to page</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default pull-right" role="button">View Details</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class=" col-md-4">
                                  <div class="thumbnail">
                                      <img src="<?php echo base_url()."assets/images/placeholder.jpg" ?>" alt="...">
                                    <div class="caption">
                                      <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                                      <p>...</p>
                                      <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Go to page</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default pull-right" role="button">View Details</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
<!--                            </div>
                            <div class="row">-->
                                <div class=" col-md-4">
                                  <div class="thumbnail">
                                      <img src="<?php echo base_url()."assets/images/placeholder.jpg" ?>" alt="...">
                                    <div class="caption">
                                      <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                                      <p>...</p>
                                      <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Go to page</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default pull-right" role="button">View Details</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class=" col-md-4">
                                  <div class="thumbnail">
                                      <img src="<?php echo base_url()."assets/images/placeholder.jpg" ?>" alt="...">
                                    <div class="caption">
                                      <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                                      <p>...</p>
                                      <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Go to page</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default pull-right" role="button">View Details</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class=" col-md-4">
                                  <div class="thumbnail">
                                      <img src="<?php echo base_url()."assets/images/placeholder.jpg" ?>" alt="...">
                                    <div class="caption">
                                      <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                                      <p>...</p>
                                      <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Go to page</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default pull-right" role="button">View Details</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            Top courses
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            List top uploaded courses
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </div>
    <!-- /#page-wrapper -->
```

Comment: You need smaller buttons for those. Or show less thumbnails per row. If you provide your code we can better help you.

Comment: yes sir, i will make those changes

Comment: Bootstraps works with percentages. If you give it a min-width, it will break everything. You need to change the design. Maybe use two columns instead of 3. Or you can change the text to show an icon instead.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap detects the browser window size to do the adaptation. Because the inspector goes inside the browser window when docked it will break you css layout.

To solve this you can create a new css class with bigger min-width property.

.my-thumbnail { min-width: 300px !important;} and add this css class to your thumbnail html element. Add important to override existing min-width.

Remember you'll have to do different ones for each of the screen sizes. You'll probably have to play with the size of the cols where the thumbnails are inside too.

Comment: As I said, you need to play with the col sizes too. If you're with the same example as in the bootstrap website you'll have 3 col-4. Maybe change to 2 col-6 and it will work. You asked for bigger thumbnails so you also need bigger containers for the thumbnails themselves.

Comment: it works fine with col-6, but now even for normal screen the thumbs are too large which also is undesirable.

Comment: Well that's what you showed on image3 isn't it? 3 columns is not enough for thumbnails with such big buttons so you have to go with two and then play with the size of the thumbnail too so they don't take the whole size of the col.

Answer (score 0):

You reduce browser to some `height` and `width` through browser console. `Bootstrap` responsiveness works on `media queries`, wherein, they will be setting relative values to respective elements based on `min-width` and `max-width` for `screen`. So it's like if it is between a range of value, then the particular styles gets applied. To know exactly how good the responsiveness is you need to use `mobile` emulator present in `chrome` browser.

[image: Mobile version]

So for example, if you see below `media query`

```
@media (min-width: 767px){
   //some styles for grid where width=600px
}

@media (min-width: 1200px){
   //some styles for grid where width=900px
}
```

Then until `768px` of screen width the `width` of `grid` will be `900px` and once it drops down it will reduce to `600px`.

**Conclusion**

Since the screen width will be fixed for different devices and won't be between any irregular values, **you should test the responsiveness either with the real `devices` or with the browser emulator which is shown in above image**

Comment: well it does seem to work in my mobile, but how can i be sure about devices with width 1000 ? and if you look carefully, i have used mobile emulator and tried for different widths. the extreme two works fine, problem lies for width range 1178-992

Comment: When you select emulator mode, you can see at the top of the browser, that you have option to change the device and orientation. Try checking with the required device you desire.

Comment: i see exact same problem for ipad when rotated, the buttons disorient.